# STL implementation of BFS : Trouble in accessing adjacency lists

Tags: c++, graph, stl

Hi I am having a problem implementing the BFS using the STL libraries in C++.
The following implementation has the problem that the adjacency lists of all nodes other than the source node come out to be empty, which terminates the traversal after visiting the source and the nodes immediately connected to it.

```
#include<list>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

class GraphNode {
    private:
        string data;
        list<GraphNode> adj_list;
        bool visited;
    public:
        // Add a constructor
        GraphNode()
        {
            visited=false;
        }
        GraphNode(string input_data)
        {
            data=input_data;
            visited=false;
        }
        // Add a neighbour to the node
        void add_edge(GraphNode input_node)
        {
            adj_list.push_back(input_node);
        }
        string return_data()
        {
            return data;
        }
        void visit()
        {
            cout<<data<<endl;
            visited=true;
        }
        bool get_visit()
        {
            return visited;
        }
        list<GraphNode> *return_adj_list()
        {
            return &adj_list;
        }

};

void BreadthFirstSearch(GraphNode g)
{
        queue<GraphNode> bfs_queue;
        //list<GraphNode> adj_list;

        GraphNode node;
        g.visit();
        bfs_queue.push(g);
        while (bfs_queue.empty()==false)
        {
            node=bfs_queue.front();
            bfs_queue.pop();
            list<GraphNode> *adj_list=node.return_adj_list();
            //cout<<node.return_data()<<":";
            for (list<GraphNode>::iterator adj_list_iter=adj_list->begin();adj_list_iter!=adj_list->end();adj_list_iter++)
            {   //cout<<adj_list_iter->return_data()<<",";
                if (!adj_list_iter->get_visit())
                {
                    adj_list_iter->visit();
                    bfs_queue.push(*adj_list_iter);
                }
            }
            //cout<<endl;
        }
}

int main()
{
    GraphNode A=GraphNode("A");
    GraphNode B=GraphNode("B");
    GraphNode C=GraphNode("C");
    GraphNode D=GraphNode("D");
    GraphNode E=GraphNode("E");
    GraphNode F=GraphNode("F");
    A.add_edge(B);
    A.add_edge(C);
    B.add_edge(C);
    C.add_edge(E);
    E.add_edge(F);
    E.add_edge(D);
    D.add_edge(C);


    BreadthFirstSearch(A);
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`add_edge` makes a copy. Changes made to `B` in `main` after it has been added to `A` does not change the copy in `A`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that I have to pass it through a pointer to resolve this issue ?

Comment: @SayanGhosh, that would be one way to resolve the issue. The other way would be to get a reference to the object in `A` from `add_edge`.